# Print Data in Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have  a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'first': [
   {'red': ['six', 'three', 'seven', 'six']},
   {'green': ['eight', 'three', 'four']}
 ],
 'second': [
   {'blue': ['one', 'five', 'three']}
 ]
}
```

How can I get to specific points in the dictionary?  For example, how can I print out the second 'six' in the 'first' header under subheading 'red'?

Comment: Do you mean the *second* "six"?

Comment: yes, sorry.  i was referring to the fourth position.

Comment: `dict_name['first'][0]['red'][3]`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dictionary is called `d` you could do this:

```
print(d['first'][0]['red'][3])
```

- The expression `d['first']` gives you the value associated with the key `'first'`. The value is a list.
- The `[0]` gives you the first element in the list (by the way, why do you have a list containing only one element?). Note that indexing is 0-based in Python.
- Then you have another dictionary whose values are again lists. The `['red']` fetches the value from this dictionary.
- The `[3]` accesses the fourth element in the list.

Comment: I was just throwing together a quick example.  Generally my lists have more than one element.  Thank you for your answer.  I knew it had to be something simple like this.

Answer (score 1):

`print mydict["first"][0]["red"][3]` will print item 3 (the fourth item, since item 0 is the first element). In this case it should give you `six`.

Also, what you have here is a `list` contained within a `dict` contained within a `list` contained within another `dict`. The numeric index `3` accesses part of that inner `list`, and isn't something that's generally useful for a `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

For the one you asked:

```
>>> a = {'first': [{'red': ['six', 'three', 'seven', 'six']}, {'green': ['eight', 'three', 'four']}], 'second': [{'blue': ['one', 'five', 'three']}]}
>>> a['first'][0]['red'][3]
'six'
```